# Reducing list of dicts A by unique key from list of dicts B

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to clean user input `new_accounts` and prevent storing duplicates in DB `db_accounts`
Currently I reduce in 2 steps: getting a list of unique ids and then filtering user input by that list

```py
# tens of dicts each with tens of keys
new_accounts = [{'id':'wh4h3r'}, {}, {}]
# thousands of dicts
db_accounts = [{'id':'l5k6jy'}, {}, {}]

filterby = {a['id'] for a in db_accounts}
new_unique = [a for a in new_accounts if a['id'] not in filterby]
```

I wonder if it's possible to simplify this code further using itertools, functools, collections, etc.?

Comment: If you're storing this in a database, why do you not just make the `id` field unique so duplicates cannot be created at the database level?

Comment: @PacketLoss but what if a) it's NoSQL or b) you want to filter it by different key or c) you want to store it in several DBs based on different logic?

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate goal is to add ids from `new_accounts` into `db_accounts` while avoiding duplicates, this code is slightly more compact than what you have.

```
filtered_accounts = set(account["id"] for account in new_accounts) - set(account["id"] for account in db_accounts)
db_accounts.extend([{"id": id} for id in filtered_accounts])
```